# Any possibilities of more than one user having same email address?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal,So this might be a premature question.

Can i have a user with same email ID who can access different domains with different role for each domain?

I will login as a admin and create a user say,

```
domain : abc
username : xyz
email address : xyz@gmail.com
role : abc
```

then i again try to create a new user with following details,

```
domain : mno
username : xyz
email address : xyz@gmail.com
role : fff
```

Now the drupal is not allowing me to create a user , but am trying to create a user to different domain having different role.

How this can be achieved.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can't use same email for several account , Drupal core allows you to add several role to one user , so you don't need to create several user for each role

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_roles several module can help

Answer (score 0):

For each role you can define what it can do and what can not. You can create any number of roles and you can assign any number of roles to the same user. But I see no point of users sharing the same account, which, with the same email address, it's exactly what it will be.